# mysqli_num_rows() returning incorrect number of rows

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

### Context:

I've created a page where users can vote on debates. The debates all have two potential options. When the user clicks on the option on the left side, it returns a value of "0". When the user clicks on the option on the right side, it returns a value of "1". After the user clicks the side they want to vote on, an AJAX call is executed, which checks the database to see if the user has already voted by checking the user ID and poll ID. The AJAX works fine. This is the jQuery/AJAX code:

```
$(".display-polls-container").on("click", "input:radio", function(e) { //when user votes on debate

    var thisElement = $(this);
    var vote_value = $(this).val();
    var pollId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().siblings().children(".poll-id").val();

    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?>

        setVote(vote_value, pollId, thisElement); //insert vote into database

    <?php } else { ?>

        alert("You must sign in to vote on a debate");

    <?php } ?>

});

function setVote(vote_value, pollId, thisElement) { //insert vote into database

    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/poll_votes.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {vote_value: vote_value, pollId: pollId, idUsers: idUsers},
        success: function(data) {

            getVote(pollId, thisElement); //if vote inserts correctly, get the vote count and apply it to the debate (this function is not relevant enough to include its code)

        },
        error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
            //console.log(error);
            //console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

}
```

### Problem:

The problem is that the PHP code isn't working at the moment. Everything seems to be working about it except the `mysqli_num_rows()` function. Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

include 'dbh.inc.php'; //include database connection

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$query = "SELECT idUsers FROM poll_votes WHERE idUsers = ? AND poll_id = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $idUsers, $poll_id);

$idUsers = $_POST['idUsers'];
$pollId = $_POST['pollId'];
$vote_value = $_POST['vote_value'];
$seen = "false";

if ($vote_value == 0) { //change value inserted into database based on which side you voted for
    
    $yes = "true";
    $no = "false";

} elseif ($vote_value == 1) {

    $yes = "false";
    $no = "true";

}

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$r = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

if ($r) {

    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 0) { //check if user has already voted on debate; this seems to be where the problem lies - it always returns 0
        
        $q = "INSERT INTO poll_votes (yes, no, poll_id, idUsers, seen) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; //insert vote into database
        $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $q);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'ssiis', $yes, $no, $pollId, $idUsers, $seen);

        $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);

        if ($execute) {
            
            echo "Vote submitted successfully!";

        }

    } else {

        echo "You can't vote twice!";

    }

}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

What happens is, even when the user has already voted on a specific debate, the query doesn't disallow them from continuing to vote on the same debate. Once the user votes once, they shouldn't be able to do it again. I try checking if they have already voted using the `mysqli_num_rows()` function, but it ALWAYS returns 0, regardless of how many rows there actually are.

### Things I have tried:

I checked the original query by submitting my own values into the "SQL" part of the mysqli database, and it worked just fine, so I don't think that the problem is with the query. I have also formed the query using non-prepared statements, which worked fine and returned the correct number of results from the database. This means that the fact that I'm using prepared statements might mean that I left something out. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: please var_dump($r) to see if your query returning data from the database.

Comment: @Hardood When I var_dump($r), this is what I get: object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) } Vote submitted successfully!

Comment: @Hardood Is there anything you can take from that?

Comment: As you can see num_rows is 0, so check your query again, make sure you pass the exact correct values to it

Comment: As i see in data: {vote_value: vote_value, pollId: pollId, idUsers: idUsers}, i think you didn't set the value of idUsers correctly.

Comment: @Hardood idUsers is defined earlier in the document, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this worked, but I just re-wrote the code to go through the motions again and see if I could notice any prior mistakes. Ultimately, I don't THINK anything was changed, but it works now.

Comment: I'd suggest closing this question - [from the help guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error* are considered off-topic.

Comment: @Don't Panic Ok, will do. Thanks.